# How Splinter get the text of <span> as output,

Tags: python, html, splinter

I have a `<tr>` whose id is dynamically generated by Javascript code so I can't select it using `find_by_id`. How can I access the text in the `span` using Splinter if I don't know what the id for its containing `<tr>` tag is going to be?

```
<tr id="treeview-1020-record-b3250a58-46d6-4df8-9e04-69d82afcc966" data-boundview="treeview-1020" data-recordid="b3250a58-46d6-4df8-9e04-69d82afcc966" data-recordindex="22" class="x-grid-row x-grid-tree-node-expanded x-grid-data-row" tabindex="-1">
    <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-treecolumn-1019 x-grid-cell-treecolumn x-grid-cell-first x-grid-cell-last x-unselectable x-grid-cell-treecolumn">
        <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner" style="text-align:left;">
            <span class="x-tree-node-text">WZ1MZ35_G2 ADV.</span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Select all your `tr` tags.
Find the one that starts with the correct string.
From that node search all your span tags. and extract the text

```
allTR = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
for (let trIdx = 0; trIdx < allTR.length; trIdx++) {
    const trElem = allTR[trIdx];
    if (trElem.getAttribute('id').startsWith('treeview-1020-')) {
        allSpan = trElem.getElementsByTagName('span');
        if (allSpan.length === 0) continue;
        spanText = allSpan[0].textContent
        // do something usefull with the text
    }
}
```